# Session and Cookie save all inputs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, session

I have 5 `div`s like this. That means there can be many `input`s are in view. Problem is How to save inputs **selection**s. **when refresh page**, **press back button**. I searched about session but my inputs can be many or less not static. that's the problem

```
<div id="account_details">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        Нэгдүгээр хэсэг
    </div>
    <?php //dd($questions) ?>
@if(count($questions) > 0)
    <div class="panel-body">
    <?php $i = 1; ?>
    @foreach ($collections[0] as $question)
        @if ($i > 1) <hr /> @endif
          <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
          <div class="form-group">
          <strong>Асуулт {{ $i++ }}.<br/><br/>{!! nl2br($question->question_text) !!}</strong><br/>
          <input type="hidden" name="questions[{{ $question->id }}]"
           value="{{ $question->id }}">
           @foreach($question->options as $option)
               <br>
               <label class="radio-inline">
               <input type="radio" name="answers[{{ $question->id }}]"
                  value="{{ $option->id }}">{{ $option->option }}</label>
           @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
    </div>
@endif
</div><input type="button" value="Дараагын хуудас" onclick="show_next('account_details','user_details','bar1');">
</div>
```

Comment: Laravel is a server-side PHP framework and therefore completely unrelated to localStorage or sessionStorage which are client-side construct. Therefore I'm not quite sure what you're asking. The question itself also seems too broad owing to the fact that you've shown no effort to solve it yourself.

Comment: Oh i'm sorry its not about Laravel let me change it. its about **php, javascript, jquery**

Comment: I don't understand what are you saying. I just said thank you for your downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SessionStorage/LocalStorage is client side component, so you can't use it from PHP code. You can save user data in server side storage like [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apc-store.php), cookies or SESSION. I think this is only way to do that.

Comment: Oh i see now. It was my mistake. But i can put in inputs in session or cookie. But cant take there all `input`s value. In that case. That's the problem

Comment: You can store informations in LocalStorage, but you need to write simple JavaScript script for this job :) Use onChange events or something else and after page refresh this script should read all data from LocalStorage/SessionStorage and pass values to inputs

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can save your inputs in a a session storage, and retrieve whenever you need. This is pretty much just another variable, but it gets stored in the session, so it will hold between page changes.

Just create a variable and save it in session storage, example:

```
var name= somecode;
sessionStorage.setItem("name", name);
```

Now when you need whatever you saved in that variable, just use:

```
sessionStorage.getItem("name");
```